# How to modify a json text to be parsable by jsonml?

Tags: java, json

My requirement is to create json string to xml with properties. Based on below thread I understand, I need to use JSONML in order to do that. But is there any way to dynamically convert/modify json text into parsable JSONML using any library or pre-defined class in json.org?

Thread: [How to Convert JSON string to xml with properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689242/how-to-convert-json-string-to-xml-with-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a json library which you can use you to convert from json string to xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

To covert to from json string to xml, first convert to JsonObject then to xml

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```